# Place anchor without tapping

Tags: android, arcore

Is there a way to place anchors without tapping the screen. I don't want to place any ar model without tapping.
So for example I placed a anchor in the center of the screen and at the midpoints of the edges, Is there a way to do it without actually tapping the respective positions on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Just take the following couple lines of code from the handleTap function in /samples/.../HelloArActivity.java but first stuff anything from the center into the hit structure:
anchors.add(hit.createAnchor());
this.runOnUiThread(this::showOcclusionDialogIfNeeded);

Answer (score 0):

As @YinOrYan says, you can leverage the standard approach to add anchors at a fixed point, for example the centre of the preview view.

You can add a button anywhere you want on your UI to actually trigger the code to add the anchor.

For example - this adds a button over the AR view:

```js
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="LineViewMainActivity">

  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_add_image" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/ux_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

  </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

You then can link code to add an anchor and renderable to the listener for that button - the code below is from an example that adds the object 1M front of the camera but you can change it as you need:

```js
 // Place the anchor 1m in front of the camera. 
            Frame frame = arFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame();
            Session session = arFragment.getArSceneView().getSession();
            Anchor newMarkAnchor = session.createAnchor(
                        frame.getCamera().getPose()
                                .compose(Pose.makeTranslation(0, 0, -1f)) //This will place the anchor 1M in front of the camera
                                .extractTranslation());
            AnchorNode addedAnchorNode = new AnchorNode(newMarkAnchor);
            addedAnchorNode.setRenderable(andyRenderable);
            addedAnchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
```